# Check for proccess, if not running execute process, Kill process every X seconds

Tags: loops, vbscript

I'm trying to write a VBScript where it checks for a process every 5 minutes, if it's not running execute it, then every 15 minutes kill that process so a new instance can start. I have the beginning part to check and start the process, but I am having trouble getting the later part to work. Here's what I have so far.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Do Until i=1
    bIsRunning = False
    For Each Process In service.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
        If Process.Name = "Service.exe" Then
            bIsRunning = True
        End If
    Next
    If Not bIsRunning Then
        WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Dustin\Programs\Service\Service.exe"
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 300000
Loop
```

I'm trying to throw something such as this into there

```
oShell.Run "taskkill /f /im Service.exe", , True
WScript.Sleep 15000
```

How would I go about throwing two sleep arguments into one script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to handle the process timeout is to check the `CreationDate` property of the WMI Process objects and compare process datetime against current datetime.

The only problem is that WMI datetimes are different from the usual VT_DATE used in VBScript. But, we can use a `WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime` ([SWbemDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393687(v=vs.85).aspx)) instance to handle the conversion.

```
Option Explicit

' WMI constants
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = 32

' Process constants. 
Const PROCESS_NAME = "service.exe"
CONST PROCESS_COMMANDLINE = "C:\Users\Dustin\Programs\Service\Service.exe"
Const PROCESS_RUNNING_MINUTES = 15

' Monitoring constants
Const SLEEP_TIME = 300000

' Grab a reference to WMI
Dim wmi
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

' Get an instance of a SWBemDateTime object to deal with WMI datetimes    
Dim swbemDT
    Set swbemDT = WScript.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

Dim bRunning, process, colProcesses
    Do While True
        ' Retrieve the list of matching processes
        Set colProcesses = wmi.ExecQuery( _
            "SELECT CreationDate From Win32_Process " & _
            "WHERE Name='" & PROCESS_NAME & "'" _ 
            ,"WQL" , wbemFlagForwardOnly _
        )

        ' Calculate when the process should have been started
        swbemDT.SetVarDate DateAdd( "n", (-1 * PROCESS_RUNNING_MINUTES), Now())

        ' We don't know if there is a valid running instance
        bRunning = False

        For Each process In colProcesses
            ' Check if the process is too old or it is a valid running instance
            If process.CreationDate < swbemDT Then 
                ' Too old, termite the process
                process.Terminate
            Else 
                ' We have found a valid running instance
                bRunning = True
            End If
        Next 

        ' If we have not found any valid running instance, start a new process
        If Not bRunning Then 
            WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run PROCESS_COMMANDLINE, 0, False 
        End If 

        ' Wait before a new process check
        WScript.Sleep SLEEP_TIME
    Loop
```